# wordpress woody snippets plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm trying to use woody snippets plugin in wordpress but can't get it to work.

Here's what I've done:

1. downloaded and activated woody snippets
2. created the following php snippet:

   ```
   <?php
     add_action('init','print2');
     function print2($str){
        $str = str_replace(",","<br>",$str);
        print $str . "<br>";
     }
   ?>
   ```
3. got the short code and added the following to a static page

   ```
    [wbcr_php_snippet id="96"]
    $test="yes";
    print2("$test");
    [/wbcr_php_snippet]
   ```

unfortunately, nothing happens.  can someone provide steps to make this work?

Comment: This works in a php tester - without using the shortcode (the function works). Have you read the documentation for the plugin? http://woody-ad-snippets.webcraftic.com/getting-started-with-woody-ad-snippets/#Creating_a_PHP_snippet You also don't need the quotes around `$test` when you are passing it to your function.

Comment: can I add this to a static page or does it have to be in a template?